# Accelerate mongo update within two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Payments collection with playerId field, which is the _id key of Person collection. I need to count once, what's the maximal payment of a person and save the value to person's document. This is how I do it now:

```
db.Person.find().forEach( function(person) {
    var cursor = db.Payment.aggregate([
        {$match: {playerId: person._id}},
        {$group: {
            _id:"$playerId",
            maxp: {$max:"$amount"}
        }}
    ]);
    var maxPay = 0;
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        maxPay = cursor.next().maxp;
    }
    person.maxPay = maxPay;
    db.Person.save(person);
});
```

I suppose seeking maxPay on Payments collection once for all Persons should be faster, but I dunno how to write that in code. Could you help me please?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Show us sample document for both collections and the expected result. Also consider to add your MongoDB server version.

Comment: `Person: {_id}, Payment: {personId, amount}`. Expected Person to have field maxPay. Using mongodb 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run just a single aggregation pipeline operation which has a **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline initially to do a "left join" on the `Payment` collection. This is necessary in order to get the data from the right collection (payments) embedded within the resulting documents as an array called `payments`.

The preceding **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** pipeline deconstructs the embedded `payments` array i.e. it will generate a new record for each and every element of the `payments` data field. It basically flattens the data which will be useful for the next **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage.

In this **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage, you calculate your desired aggregates by applying the accumulator expression(s). If for instance your `Person` schema has other fields you wish to retain, then the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator operator should suffice in addition to the **[`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)** operator for the extra `maxPay` field.

---

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, there is no operator to "include all fields" in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** aggregation pipeline operation. This is because the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step is mostly used to group and calculate/aggregate data from collection fields (sum, avg, etc.) and returning all the collection's fields is not the pipeline's intended purpose. The group pipeline operator is similar to the SQL's `GROUP BY` clause where you can't use `GROUP BY` unless you use any of the aggregation functions (accumulator operators in MongoDB). The same way, if you need to retain most fields, you have to use an aggregation function in MongoDB as well. In this case, you have to apply **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** to each field you want to keep.

You can also use the **[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)** system variable which references the root document. Keep all fields of this document in a field within the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)**  pipeline, for example:

```
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "maxPay": { "$max": "$payments.amount" },
        "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
    }
}
```

The drawback with this approach is you would need a further **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline to reshape the fields so that they match the original schema because the documents from the resulting pipeline will have only three fields; `_id`, `maxPay` and the embedded `doc` field.

---

The final pipeline stage, **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)**, writes the resulting documents of the aggregation pipeline to the same collection, akin to updating the `Person` collection by atomically replacing the existing collection with the new results collection. The **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operation does not change any indexes that existed on the previous collection. If the aggregation fails, the **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out)** operation makes no changes to the pre-existing collection:

```
db.Person.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Payment",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "playerId",
            "as": "payments"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": { 
        "path": "$payments", 
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true 
    } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "maxPay": { "$max": "$payments.amount" },
            /* extra fields for demo purposes
            "firstName": { "$first": "$firstName" }, 
            "lastName": { "$first": "$lastName" }
            */
        }
    },
    { "$out": "Person" }
])
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know about $lookup. But there is a problem with it. Only persons having at least one payment are saved. Also, is there any way to save other person's fields without listing them all?

Comment: Including the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option in `$unwind` should solve the first problem (as in the updated answer). As for the other question, I've answered that in the same update.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation!